# jQuery mobile stops file uploads by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, input, types, input-type-file

When using jQuery mobile as a script in a web page for styling purpose,

```
(<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

The `<input type=file>` doesn't work. 
Any one know why ?

Comment: This is same for the jQuery non-mobile script as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this error exists whatever the jQuery mobile script version you include in your web page.

So whatever the jQuery script version you use the only thing you need to do to resolve this file upload issue is just include this `data-ajax="false"` inside your `<form>` tag.

Like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
```

Then file uploads WORK well with proper jQuery styles as well, version doesn't matter :)

Comment: Same above solution works for the JQuery non-mobile script issue as well.